# Do you need a new instance of IndexReader and IndexSearcher every time?

Tags: java, lucene

In a web application, I'm having one `IndexReader` and one respective `IndexSearcher` for the whole application.

The documentation says they are thread-safe, so that's ok, but is it supposed to work properly if the underlying index changes (e.g. an `IndexWriter` makes changes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to reopen the reader.

Use the [SearcherManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html) to automatically update the reader, calling [maybeRefresh](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ReferenceManager.html#maybeRefresh%28%29) when you've made changes.

Samples of Scala code below:

```
@volatile protected var LAST_SEARCHER_REFRESH = 0
protected lazy val SEARCHER_MANAGER = new SearcherManager (LUCENE_DIR, new SearcherFactory {
  override def newSearcher (reader: IndexReader): IndexSearcher = {new IndexSearcher (reader)}
})

...

if (LAST_SEARCHER_REFRESH != Time.relativeSeconds()) {LAST_SEARCHER_REFRESH = Time.relativeSeconds(); SEARCHER_MANAGER.maybeRefresh()}
val searcher = SEARCHER_MANAGER.acquire(); try {
  searcher.search (query, collector)
  ...
} finally {SEARCHER_MANAGER.release (searcher)}
```

Sometimes you'll have to implement your own caching though, like [when you need to synchronize the IndexReader with TaxonomyReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html#concurrent_indexing_search). [IndexSearcher description](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) has recommendations about how to do that (there is a fast path via [DirectoryReader.open(IndexWriter, applyAllDeletes)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#open%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter,%20boolean%29) to make a new reader from a writer used to commit the changes).